# Writing out a list of linkbuttons dynamically with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeat

I need to write out a list of link buttons in a ul li list like below. With this being a combination of html and a asp.net control how can i do it?

```
<li><asp:LinkButton OnCommand="LinkButton_Command" CssClass="main1 subTag" ID="LinkButton1"
                                    runat="server" CommandArgument="Summer Glow">Summer Glow</asp:LinkButton></li>
<li><asp:LinkButton OnCommand="LinkButton_Command" CssClass="main1 subTag" ID="LinkButton2"
                                    runat="server"  CommandArgument="Festival Chic">Festival Chic</asp:LinkButton></li>
<li><asp:LinkButton OnCommand="LinkButton_Command" CommandArgument="Beach Glamour" CssClass="main1 subTag" ID="LinkButton3"
                                    runat="server">Beach Glamour</asp:LinkButton></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use asp.net repeater to create UL, give it an id and get its reference in code behind. In your code behind create LinkButtons dynamically and append them to the UL.